# Proper steps for a React Native iOS release build

Tags: ios, react-native

This is just a case of lack of documentation thus far, but when creating a production release build of an iOS React Native app, after setting the Build/Archive schemes to be Release instead of debug, do I need to manually create a `main.bundle` *and* uncomment the second `jsCodeLocation` line in `AppDelegate.m`, or does something handle that for me automatically?

I've been doing both steps manually thus far, but I'm sure there will be a day that I forget to do so, and I wanted to know what the compile and build scripts are doing for me and what I need to do myself.

(Using react-native@0.21 if applicable.)

Comment: Hi Joshua were you able to figure this out? I am trying to release my app, I did succesfully for Android, but iOS is really giving me a hard time. Is there a tutorial you can recommend?

Comment: @Noitidart I haven't done a release super recently, but the process changed a bit. You no longer need to worry about the `jsCodeLocation` in new versions. Other things might have changed as well.

Comment: Thanks very much for mentioning about the `jsCodeLocation` - I was still changing it and my stuff failing. If you do get a chance to share some more info  I would super duper appreciate it. In all my searching I still had not found out that I should not adjust jsCodeLocation, but you just cleared that up in a sec with such a short comment! Thank you! :)

Comment: Josh I figured it out, if you ever need help let me know please.

Comment: Awesome @Noitidart! And thank you.

Answer (score 3):

on our App we have made that our Build System generate App.plist (with some env contextual client ids/tokens/api urls of service) and we have a property boolean that indicates if the app needs to use bundle or not.

Based on this we switch the mode to use (use bundle VS use live reload server).

I submitted some months ago a PR to bring this in the skeleton, this never goes through though, but feel free to implement your own: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/2101

Also one interesting thing we use to generate our App.plist based on env is a script that basically do this: https://twitter.com/greweb/status/687575516862349312

Hope this helps